# Elasticsearch date range filter changes score

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Using the query below, removing the `must` returns some of the same items as using the range but the scores and therefore ranking is different. It's as if the date filters are altering the score. I don't want that, I just want the filter to restrict what is returned not reorder them.

Is there a way to filter by date that does not affect the score or ranking?

```
{
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                "terms": {
                    "title": ["surface", "ipad", "nexus"]
                }
            }, {
                "terms": {
                    "tags": ["mobile_acc"]
                }
            }],
            "must": [{
                "constant_score": {
                    "filter": {
                        "range": {
                            "availabledate": {
                                "lte": "2015-08-30T12:24:41-07:00"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "constant_score": {
                    "filter": {
                        "range": {
                            "expiredate": {
                                "gt": "2015-08-30T12:24:41-07:00"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `"boost": 0` for your `constant_score`s:

```
  "must": [
    {
      "constant_score": {
        "filter": {
          "range": {
            "availabledate": {
              "lte": "2015-08-30T12:24:41-07:00"
            }
          }
        },
        "boost": 0
      }
    },
    {
      "constant_score": {
        "filter": {
          "range": {
            "expiredate": {
              "gt": "2015-08-30T12:24:41-07:00"
            }
          }
        },
        "boost": 0
      }
    }
  ]
```